# Display loading animation while starting up a form in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, animation, loading

I understand this might be asked before :

[Show a loading screen in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403202/show-a-loading-screen-in-vb-net)

But anyone can provide me something like :

```
' Show Loading Screen  
  --> Do anything like initializing or updating UI
' Close Loading Screen
```

In this case I can fire (Show Loading Screen) anywhere in the form I want,
Like

```
Dim LoadingScreen as New LoadingScreen
LoadingScreen.ShowLoading()
' Do things
'
'
LoadingScreen.StopLoading()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Yet_Another_Splash_Screen.aspx