# CrystalReportViewer.RefreshReport hangs when running from BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, backgroundworker, freeze

I'm trying to "enhance" my reporting code by adding a loading screen while the Crystal Report is being prepared/loaded. Before I started trying to add the loading screen, all of my reports would come up just fine, but the cursor change just wasn't "enough" of an indication that the application was still working on pulling the report - some of them can take a while - so I wanted to provide a more "obvious" visual cue.

In order to accomplish this, I've put the report creation method calls into a `BackgroundWorker` that exists in the loading screen itself (*I haven't gotten around to learning how to use `Async/Await` well enough yet to feel comfortable using that instead*). The loading screen comes up correctly and everything *appears* to work as expected until it actually attempts to display the report on screen. At that point, the "**Please wait while the document is processing.**" box comes up (*in the `CrystalReportViewer` control in the form used to display reports*), but it just sits there, not even spinning. Eventually, my IDE throws an error about receiving a `ContextSwitchDeadlock` and I pretty much just have to cancel execution.

Here's my `dlgReportLoading` "splash screen" with a `PictureBox` control that contains an animated GIF:

```vb
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class dlgReportLoading
    Private DisplayReport As Common.CRReport
    Private WithEvents LoadReportWorker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

    Public Sub New(ByRef Report As Common.CRReport)
        InitializeComponent()
        DisplayReport = Report
    End Sub

    Private Sub dlgReportLoading_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Me.TopMost = True
        Me.TopMost = False

        LoadReportWorker = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
        LoadReportWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub dlgReportLoading_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadReport_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles LoadReportWorker.DoWork
        If Not DisplayReport.ReportOption = Common.CRReport.GenerateReportOption.None Then
            Select Case DisplayReport.ReportOption
                Case Common.CRReport.GenerateReportOption.DisplayOnScreen
                    '-- This is the method I'm currently testing
                    DisplayReport.ShowReport()
                Case Common.CRReport.GenerateReportOption.SendToPrinter
                    DisplayReport.PrintReport()
                Case Common.CRReport.GenerateReportOption.ExportToFile
                    DisplayReport.ExportReport()
            End Select
        End If

        DisplayReport.ReportOption = Common.CRReport.GenerateReportOption.None

        '--
        '-- This code was in use before trying to generate the reports in the background
        'If Not DisplayReport.CrystalReport Is Nothing Then
        '    DisplayReport.CrystalReport.Dispose()
        'End If
        '--
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadReport_Complete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles LoadReportWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

As noted in the code above, I'm currently testing the `ShowReport()` method as defined here:

```vb
        Protected Friend Sub ShowReport()
            Dim ReportViewer As frmReportPreview

            Me.PrepareReport()
            ReportViewer = New frmReportPreview(Me)

            With ReportViewer
                .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
                .Show()
            End With
        End Sub
```

And the `frmReportPreview` is this:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class frmReportPreview
    Private DisplayReport As Common.CRReport
    Private ReportToDisplay As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

    Public Sub New(ByRef Report As Common.CRReport)
        InitializeComponent()

        DisplayReport = Report
        PrepareReportForDisplay()

        Me.rptViewer.ReportSource = Nothing
        Me.rptViewer.ReportSource = ReportToDisplay

        ' SET ZOOM LEVEL FOR DISPLAY:
        '    1 = Page Width
        '    2 = Whole Page
        '    25-100 = zoom %
        Me.rptViewer.Zoom(1)
        Me.rptViewer.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmReportPreview_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        '-- HANGS HERE
        Me.rptViewer.RefreshReport()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmReportPreview_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        ReportToDisplay.Dispose()
        Me.rptViewer.ReportSource = Nothing
    End Sub
    
    '...CODE FOR PREPARING THE REPORT TO BE DISPLAYED
End Class
```

The `dlgReportLoading` form pops up correctly and the animation plays until the `frmReportPreview` pops up in front of it (it doesn't close). The little box that has what is normally an animated spinning circle indicating the report data is being loaded appears, but almost immediately freezes in place.

I have a breakpoint in the `LoadReport_DoWork()` method of my `dlgReportLoading` form after the call to the `ShowReport()` method, but it never gets to that point. I also have one in the `LoadReport_Complete()` method of that form that it never hits either and that dialog never actually closes.

I put another breakpoint at the end of the `frmReportPreview_Shown` method, right after the `Me.rptViewer.RefreshReport()` call, but it never hits that either, so it seems clear that this is where things are getting stuck, but *only* when the report is being generated through the `BackgroundWorker`. If I just call the `ShowReport()` method without sending it through the "splash screen" and `BackgroundWorker`, everything generates and displays normally.

I've tried putting the `RefreshReport()` method into its *own* `BackgroundWorker` with no change in the behavior. I've tried making the `frmReportPreview` object display modally with `ShowDialog()` instead of just `Show()`. None of this seems to help the issue.

I have a feeling something is being disposed of too early somewhere, but I can't figure out what that would be. I can provide the rest of the report preparation code from `frmReportPreview` if required, but that all *seems* to be working without error, as far as I can tell. I'm not averse to trying alternate methods of accomplishing my goal of showing the user a loading screen while all the report preparation is taking place - e.g., `Async/Await` or other multi-threading methods - so ***any*** suggestions are welcome. Please let me know if any additional clarification is needed.

---

### ENVIRONMENT

Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 21H1 (OS build 19043.1348)
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 (v15.9.38)
Crystal Reports for .NET Framework v13.0.3500.0 (Runtime version 2.0.50727)

---

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that this whole mess is being called from a `GenerateReport()` method in my `CRReport` class defined as:

```vb
Public Sub GenerateReport(ByVal ReportGeneration As GenerateReportOption)
    Me.ReportOption = ReportGeneration

    If Me.ReportOption = GenerateReportOption.None Then
        '...CODE FOR REQUESTING A GENERATION OPTION FROM THE USER
    End If

    Dim ReportLoadingScreen As New dlgReportLoading(Me)

    ReportLoadingScreen.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Which, in turn, is being called from my main form like this:

```
Private Sub PrintMyXMLReport(ByVal XMLFile As IO.FileInfo)
    Dim MyXMLReport As New IO.FileInfo("\\SERVER\Applications\Reports\MyXMLReport.rpt")
    Dim Report As New Common.CRReport(MyXMLReport, XMLFile)
    
    Report.GenerateReport(Common.CRReport.GenerateReportOption.DisplayOnScreen)
End Sub
```

Comment: `a BackgroundWorker that exists in the loading screen itself` what does this mean?

Comment: @djv - I create/instantiate the `BackgroundWorker` object in the `dlgReportLoading` form when it is instantiated as in the example provided by @OwenP in "[Show a loading screen in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/403292/2569697)". In other words, I'm not using a `BackgroundWorker` object that was instantiated before the loading screen is shown. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I was trying to provide as thorough and clear a picture as possible.

Comment: TBH it's a lot of code to look at, so I didn't really get a good idea of what you're doing at first glance. I see the sample, and looks like it should work. But I don't like the idea of your background worker being defined inside a loading screen, and that would be my critique of that sample. To separate the UI and business logic, the caller shouldn't know the UI exists. I'm not sure if this order of thread calling across UI and non-UI threads has anything to do with it but personally I would not call it according to that sample.

Comment: @djv - Thanks. Yeah, I included pretty much *all the codez* in case anyone had the time and inclination to look through and find any obvious issues. I too was thinking that the `BackgroundWorker` inside the loading screen might perhaps have at least *something* to do with the problem, but the fact that everything seems to work *up to* and *except for* the `RefreshReport()` method call is what's throwing me. Especially since it only breaks when running from a `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Ok, well now I've actually peeked at your code :) and you know the `BackgroundWorker` is run on a non-ui thread, at least LoadReport_DoWork is, so you shouldn't do UI operations. But inside `ShowReport` you create a new form and show it. You should invoke that call on the UI. In order to do that you need some sort of reference to a form or control on the UI. But, I think better yet show the report from the `LoadReport_Complete` method because that is invoked back to the caller, which is the dialog and running on the UI in your case if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @djv - Thank you for the insight. I believe I'm going to have to step back and rethink the whole process. I probably need to make separate calls to my loading screen from the "preparation" code used in each of the individual methods called by my `GenerateReport()` method instead of trying to make it so generic. I *knew* it couldn't be that easy... :P

Comment: I think you should split up `Protected Friend Sub ShowReport() Me.PrepareReport() ReportViewer.Show()` into two methods: `PrepareReport` and `ShowReport`, where the contents should be self evident, then call prepare report in `LoadReport_DoWork`, and show report in `LoadReport_Complete`. Before you start over, first try that. I am eager to see if that works.

Comment: OMG! You're a freaking LIFE-SAVER!!! (*and not the candy*) The `PrepareReport()` method was already distinct (but private), so I changed it to a `Protected Friend` method, put *that* in the `DoWork` handler, commented it out from the `ShowReport` method (to avoid duplication), then moved the whole `Select Case` block into the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler. Everything seems to be working exactly as expected now! Thank you SO much. Post that suggestion as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it! (I can provide the final code implementation as well) :D

Comment: And, I *think* it makes sense now. The issue still exists that the `RefreshReport()` method is going to hang when not being executed on the UI thread, but by moving it to the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler of the loading form, it's been "handed back" to the UI for continuation. It's so simple, but I'm certain I never would've figured that bit out on my own. :P

Comment: Great. I personally have only used BackgroundWorker sparingly and have more experience with `System.Threading.Thread` and `Async / Await`. But the principle of cross-threading between UI and non-UI applies still, and knowing how each of the `BackgroundWorker` events are run is key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the heavy lifting and UI operations into distinct methods in order to put them into the appropriate BackgroundWorker events:

```vb
Protected Friend Sub PrepareReport()
    ' perform long-running background work
End Sub

Protected Friend Sub ShowReport()
    Dim ReportViewer = New frmReportPreview(Me) With {.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized}
    ReportViewer.Show()
End Sub
```

```vb
Private DisplayReport As Common.CRReport

Private Sub LoadReport_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles LoadReportWorker.DoWork
    DisplayReport.PrepareReport()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadReport_Complete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles LoadReportWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    DisplayReport.ShowReport()    
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

because `LoadReport_DoWork` actually runs on a new non-UI thread, and `LoadReport_Complete` runs on the caller thread, which is a UI thread. Only there can you interact with the UI and show Forms etc.